# ng-class not assigning properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I'm trying to apply a class based on the scope value.

**Angularjs**

```
var ma = angular.module('ma', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
```

*Controller*

```
ma.controller('maCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource){
    $scope.mainmenuState === 'ss'; 
}]);
```

*Directive*

```
ma
    .directive('toggleAside', function(){
       return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                element.on('click', function(){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.mainmenuState === 'mm';
                    })
                })
            }
       }
    })
```

**HTML for click event (toggleMainmenu)**

```
<div toggle-aside></div>
```

**HTML for Switch Class**

```
<aside data-ng-class="{ 'toggled': mainmenuState === "mm" }"></aside>
```

But nothing happened when I click the div. Its not even print the mainmenuState.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwKEOB

Answer (score 0):

In your directive's JS code it should be

```
scope.mainmenuState = 'mm';
```

You compared the old value with 'mm' instead of replacing the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
ma.controller('maCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource){
       $scope.mainmenuState = 'ss'; 
}]);
```

Directive

```
.directive('toggleAside', function(){
   return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.on('click', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.mainmenuState = 'mm';
                })
            })
        }
   }
})
```